# Java NumberFormatException Error

Tags: java, error-handling, exception

Hey guys this is a code where I am trying to make java read a text file.I have some float values I want the program to read but it is throwing a Number Format Exception.The text file "h.txt" is a notepad file that is encoded in ANSI.

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.lang.*;
public class JavaApplication1 {

int[][] adj=new int[50][50];
String line;
 public JavaApplication1(int[][] adj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     this.adj=adj;
 }
public void fileinput2() {
try {
        BufferedReader file=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("h.txt"));
        try {
            while((line=file.readLine())!=null){
                String[] s=line.split("\t+")
                                    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
                                    {
                                    float x=Float.valueOf(s[i].trim());
                                    System.out.print(x+" ");
                                    }
                                   System.out.println();
                }
        } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

 public static void main(String[] args) {

      {
  int[][] adj=new int[50][50];
JavaApplication1 m=new JavaApplication1(adj);
m.fileinput2();        
}
}
}

}
```

The h.txt is a text file whose first line is

```
0    0.25    3
```

Java is giving me a NumberFormatException:-

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.25"
at     java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.fileinput2(JavaApplication1.java:35)
at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:70)
```

Kindly help me out.Thanks :)

Comment: are you sure 0    0.25    3 are sparated by tabs ans not spaces?

Comment: Can't you see the issue here? in the stacktrace, Integer.parseInt(), the problem is we do not know what line 35 in your code actually is,

Answer (score 0):

Change your `split` line to:

```
String[] s = line.split(" ");
```

And change your `for loop` to:

```
for (String string : s) {
    if (!string.isEmpty()) {
        float x = Float.parseFloat(string);
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
0.25
```

> is not valid Integer value hence its failing to parse value use
>   appropiate datatype like. double or float for your requirement.

i.e.    `Float.parseFloat(variable)`